# Link html using source

Tags: html

I have tried:

```
<html src="navbar.html"></html>
```

I have a file called `navbar.html`

Is there any way I could make it appear on every page I have?

I will be changing the navbar a lot throughout my website and I don't want to change it in all my 20+ pages. How can I make this one file appear in every page?

Would it be possible to make it in `html` rather than `jquery` and append it to every page?

something similar to

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

But html src

Comment: [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8988855/669576)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use PHP? As long as you're developing on a server (as PHP is server side) you can essentially change `.html` files to `.php` and include a file for the navbar. For example:

```
<?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
```

Look up PHP include at http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php. It will do exactly what you want. All you do is include the file on every page and it will be reflected in every page .

Comment: i cant use php because its server side, i need it to be client side.

Comment: mmmm..... include a javascript file in every page and use  "get element by id " ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
```

The href attribute specifies the destination address (http://www.w3schools.com/html/) of the link.

The link text is the visible part (Visit our HTML tutorial).

Clicking on the link text will send you to the specified address.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp